# python loggers as children of __main__

Tags: python, logging

I'm having trouble getting child loggers named properly in python (2.7). I have the following file structure:

```
-mypackage
  -__init__.py
  -main.py
  -log
    -__init__.py
    -logfile.log
  -src
    -__init__.py
    -logger.py
    -otherfile.py
```

The contents of main.py are:

```
import logging
import src.logger
from src.otherfile import Foo

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info('Logging from main')
foo = Foo()
```

The contents of otherfile.py are:

```
import logging
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.info('Logging from class in otherfile')
```

The contents of logger.py are:

```
import os
import logging
logdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
logfile = os.path.join(logdir, '../log/controller.log')
logger = logging.getLogger('__main__')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

fh = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - $(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(fh)

logger.info('logging from logger.py')
```

I used `logging.getLogger(__name__)` in each file based on [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects). The exception is logger.py, where I name the logger `__main__` so that it would run from top down and not try to derive everything from a buried file.

When I run main.py, it logs correctly from logger.py and main.py, but the logger from otherfile.py isn't derived correctly from the main logger.

How do I get the logger in otherfile.py to derive from my main logger?

Comment: Make sure to use backticks around `__main__` as markdown will otherwise interpret it as bold text, it just happened to me ;)

Comment: After your first sentence, I immediately checked the date of this post, and my immediate reaction after that was **why are you using Python 2.7 in 2017**????? LOL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In logger.py you are configuring the `"__main__"` logger. I was tricked by the fact that in main.py you use `__name__`. Since you are invoking `python main.py`, `__name__` evaluates to `"__main__"`. Right.

This can become a problem since when imported (instead of executed), main.py's logger won't be `"__main__"` but `"main"`. It can be fixed by making your package executable: rename `main.py` to `__main__.py` and running your package like this:

```
python -m mypackage
```

This way, logger names (actually module `__name__`'s) will remain consistent.

That said, in no way the logger that you configure in `logger.py` is a parent of the logger in `otherfile.py`. The real parent of that logger is called `"mypackage"` but you haven't configured it, so it's logs are invisible.

You have several choices, you can configure (set log level, handler and formatter):

- the root logger : `logger = logging.getLogger()`
- mypackage's logger : `logger = logger.getLogger(__name__)` in `mypackage.__init__`
- ... or go down to the level of granularity you wish.

Comment: I've tried that too. No dice. The `__name__`s come back as, for example, `src.otherfile` and so don't get linked to the main logger either way.

Comment: That is what I tried the first time. Still no success.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer as I was misguided by several elements. I have tested it on my setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create hierarchies of loggers by calling separating levels of loggers by a dot ("."). For example, the logger returned by calling `logging.getLogger('__main__.' + __name__)` inherits all properties from the logger returned by `logging.getLogger('__main__')`. This behaviour is described here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#module-level-functions.

Comment: This works for the two cases outlined in the original question. It doesn't work however for files at the same level as `main.py`. Is putting something else at the same level just bad form? Or am I making another mistake? Also, is using `__main__` the idiomatic base logger? The link specifically demurs on this point.